# Google Content Experiements - Add onClick Event With Div?

Tags: html, onclick, google-analytics

I have an image of a video which is linked, and it is surrounded by Div tag that launches my content locker. I want to track how many times people open the content locker using Google Content Experiments (I have a separate goal setup for actual completion of the locker).

The div class "link_loc" launches my locker successfully, but I'm not sure about the onClick event working correctly with Google Content Experiments.

So this is the code I have... is this correct?

```html
<div class="link_loc" 
  onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ExperimentConversions', 'Click', 'Video']); return false;">
  <a href="http://example.com/">
    <img class="size-full wp-image-8 aligncenter" title="Play Video" 
      src="http://example.com/video_player_image.jpg" alt="Play Video" 
      width="640" height="366">
  </a>
</div>
```

I have searched for a solution but am still very confused (I'm not very technical minded).

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Please post the code for how you open the "locker" using `$("div.link_loc")`